# An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I got this error while adding WSDL into my ASP.NET Core Web API project using .NET 7.0. However, it works fine using SOAP UI when company's VPN is connected.

> Cannot import wsdl:port\r\nDetail: \r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:telmaServices']/wsdl:service[@name='telmaServices']/wsdl:port[@name='mbJIRServicePort']
> Cannot import wsdl:binding\r\nDetail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.\r\nXPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:telmaServices']/wsdl:portType[@name='mbJIRServicePortType']\r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:telmaServices']/wsdl:binding[@name='mbJIRServiceBinding']
> Cannot import wsdl:portType\r\nDetail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter\r\nError: These members may not be derived.\r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:telmaServices']/wsdl:portType[@name='mbJIRServicePortType']

Comment: I had same issue, I didnt find any solition
Cannot import wsdl:port\r\nDetail: \r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='PlanlananSeferSaati']/wsdl:port[@name='PlanlananSeferSaatiSoap']
Cannot import wsdl:binding\r\nDetail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.\r\nXPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='PlanlananSeferSaatiSoap']\r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl: